# Проблема с image ресурсами в папке drawble

Tags: android-studio

При попытке запустить приложение выскакивает такая ошибка в консоль

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\drawable\dela.jpeg   [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\drawable\dela.xml  [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\values\refs.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\drawable\dela.jpeg   [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\drawable\dela.xml  [drawable/dela] E:\Android projects\PsihologiaCheloveka\app\src\main\res\values\refs.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Comment: она пишет, что у вас в одной папке несколько файлов с одинаковыми именами. Такого быть не должно, так как в этом случае невозможно присвоить id ресурсу

Comment: Попробуйте `clean` проекту сделать

Comment: не помогает, теперь все ресурсы картинки итд стали красного цвета сделал и ребилд и клин

Comment: просит переименовать все названия ресурсов в коде выделенные красным цветом

Comment: то есть по факту в одной папке у вас нет файлов с одинаковыми именами, но студия считает, что они там есть?

Comment: В ошибке вообще указано, что один файл `xml`, а второй `jpeg` - это так? Если да - один надо удалить

Comment: поудалял пока что оба файла но id imageview в коде все равно красные как main_activity в методе onCreate тоже красный